# insert date time now to sql.

Tags: java

hi at now i want insert date time now to sql. In sql the data type is datetime:
And this is my convert:

```
java.util.Date utilDate = new Date();
// Convert it to java.sql.Date
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
```

then now i cannot add it to sql. Because the

```
stmt.setDate(2, date);
```

is only add date. I try setTimestamp but it occurs error. So which one would i use? Or i can separate add date one column and time one column. How can i add time? tks

Comment: you can directly use `java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date();` as `java.sql.Date extends java.util.Date`

Comment: `java.sql.Date` is only *meant* to be a date. What error did you get when you used `Timestamp`?

Comment: you can use [java.sql.Timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html)

Comment: The only reason for an error, would be the column selection, numbered from 1. Or the field in SQL has a naming conflict, like naming the field 'date'. Both seem unlikely errors. @Nandkumar is right. Of course you might use NOW() in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use java.sql.Timestamp

see the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) for more help

Answer (score 0):

You can also replace this parameter with portable ANSI SQL [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()](http://users.atw.hu/sqlnut/sqlnut2-chp-4-sect-4.html) function.

For example:

```
insert into table (ts_column, other_column, ...) values (current_timestamp(), ?, ...);
```